# Using a TextField inside an InkWell puts focus on the entire InkWell

Tags: flutter, dart

If I type input in a `TextField` with `keyboardType: TextInputType.number` inside an `InkWell`, it triggers the ripple effect of `Inkwell` too.
Also I have notice this only happen on

- Android: both Emulator and real device
- IOS: Simulator with connect HardWare Keyboard

```
    Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: 200,
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: const Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    width: 100,
                    child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number, // This line cause issue
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Test',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

[image]

Comment: This does seem very strange yeah. It also happens on web by the way, regardless of the keyboardType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it happens or how to prevent the `InkWell` from focussing, but for your usecase it might be simply easiest to just remove the focussed color which can be done by giving this to the `InkWell`:

```
focusColor: Colors.transparent,
```

It also has a `canRequestFocus` field that you can set to false, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes, this can solve the problem temporarily, but it is still quite strange. Flutter has a lot of strange things